# Proper way to remove ads

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, iad, ads

I have an app that displays an ad, and I have given the user the option to remove ads for $0.99

The in-app purchase system works great, but what is the proper protocol for removing an ad from an app?

Right now I'm displaying my ad like so:

```
ADBannerView *adView;
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 32)];

    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                             ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50,
                                             ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32,
                                             nil];

    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;

    adView.delegate = self;
    [self addSubview:adView];

//adView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    CGAffineTransform transformAV = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(((-90*3.14159265358979323846264338327950288)/(180)));
//rotate to fit landscape display
    adView.transform = transformAV;
    adView.center = CGPointMake(303, 240);
//translate to be at bottom of screen.
```

Also, since it's a landscape-only ad should I remove this part of the code from the `requiredContentSizeIdentifiers`? I'm new to iAd:

```
ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user purchases this no ad feature you should create an NSDefaults bool set to YES to indicate this. than just query this NSDefault before adding the ad subview. if it is set to YeS than the subview should not be added . You can also use the bool to determine whether to setup the ad code entirely.

Comment: But my question is will something like [adView removeFromSuperview]; work for actually removing my ads? I don't want to have the code sent to Apple saying that the ads are displaying when in-fact they are not... Is just removing the view the proper protocol for removing an adView?